# Ionic 4 Ios build getting blank screen

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am getting `Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.` error when run app in iOS emulate and device, it is working fine in Android.

I have updated iOS platform version but still getting same error. I have try with removing plugin but still same error. Check screenshot [image]

I have setup new blank ionic 4 project and build ios it is working fine.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.8.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.0.0-beta.24
   @capacitor/core : 1.0.0-beta.24

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 (update available: 0.8.1)
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.2.9)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/chetan/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

Answer (score 4):

I find at a solution for this problem, follow the next step:

1) close Xcode;

2) Make sure localhost is allowed in config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
<platform name="ios">
...
```

Run

```
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
$ rm -rf platforms/
$ rm -rf plugins/
```

inside of the tag platform ios

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

finally run:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution of the error

**Adding WKWebView to your app**

In order to add WKWebView, we need to add the plugin from the Ionic repository.

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save`

If you already had the plugin installed, or were using a different version/fork, you’ll need to uninstall what you have first.

`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-WKWebView-engine`

And that’s it! Once the plugin install is done, your next native build will include a faster, lighter, and more modern webview!

https://ionicframework.com/blog/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/