# Ionic 4 error ios file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E5E616C0-4389-4848-80FC-6B7EFAF90D41/…/index.html

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native, cordova-ios

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem with the platform IOS,
when running the application show the splash screen and after the screen shows a white screenshot

**this is the stack shown in the execution (xcode)**
[image]

**the application stays like this**
[image]

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : not installed
   @capacitor/core : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   ios-sim : ios-sim/9.0.0 darwin-x64 node-v10.17.0
   NodeJS  : v10.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.11.3
   OS      : macOS Catalina
```

Comment: Did you find a solution please?

Comment: Solve it with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071588/7535525